# T-test for preprocessed microarray data

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am completely new to Bioinformatics but I have a microarray data file (txt) with preprocessed data that's already log 2 transformed. It looks something like this:

ProbeID     GSM1843834_BCR_T100_Probe40.CEL GSM1843835_BCR_T101_Probe44.CEL
1007_s_at    6.21000831                       6.990158924
1255_g_at    9.335597098                  8.343160084
1552271_at   3.912098064                  4.29430522

Basically, it's a dataframe with a total of 54675 rows (Probe IDs) and 21 columns which are the BCR or CLRT groups. BCR is from columns 2 to 11 and CTRL are from columns 12 to 21.

I am trying to do a t-test and limma test to see if there's any significantly different genes between the "BCR" and "CLRT" groups and select    significant genes at the  cutoff of BH-FDR  Adjusted p-value < 0.01 level and Fold  Change> 2 or <-2 (0.5))

This is my code so far which for whatever reason, won't work:

```
pvalue.BCR.CTRL<-apply(preprocessed.data,1,function(x){t.test(x[2:11],x[12:21])$p.value})
```

Error message I am getting:
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y) :
 Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
 Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Not sure what to do to fix this? I ran a str on my dataframe and as far as I can tell, all the columns are numeric..

Comment: Do you want to apply `t.test` for every row separately or you need `t.test(preprocessed.data[2:11], preprocessed.data[12:21])` ?

Comment: I need to do the t test for every row separately, yes.

Comment: Basically, every row is a different gene and I'm trying to test for differentially expressed genes between the two groups "BCR" and "CTRL".

Comment: I tried to create a sample dataset and ran `t.test` on it row-wise and it worked fine. So difficult to tell without sample of your data. Can you update your question with  `dput(head(preprocessed.data))` so that we get an idea how is your data actually?